# Google TagManager Bug : Double events are fired while we are pushing one

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services, google-tag-manager

The below is all code i am using for sending push event on data layer of tagmanager. Including init of tagmanager.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.ContainerHolder;
import com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.DataLayer;
import com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.TagManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendOpenScreenWithDeviceInfo("HEllo world","hello world", MainActivity.this);
            }
        });

        initTagmanager(this);

    }


    public static void sendOpenScreenWithDeviceInfo(final String screenName, final String vertical, final Context context) {

        DataLayer dataLayer = TagManager.getInstance(context).getDataLayer();
        dataLayer.pushEvent("openScreen", DataLayer.mapOf("screenName", screenName));

    }

    public static void initTagmanager(Context context) {
        prepareTagManager(BuildConfig.CONTAINER_ID_1, R.raw.defaultcontainer_binary_1, context);
        prepareTagManager(BuildConfig.CONTAINER_ID_2, R.raw.defaultcontainer_binary_2, context);
    }

    public static void prepareTagManager(String containerName, int rawContainer,final Context context) {
        try {
            TagManager tagManager = TagManager.getInstance(context);
            PendingResult<ContainerHolder> pending =
                            tagManager.loadContainerPreferNonDefault(containerName,
                        rawContainer);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("GTM", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
    }

}
```

When i click on the button once it prints this log.

```
06-11 15:02:34.657 22292 22932 D GAv4    : Hit delivery requested: ht=1497173554549, _s=23, _v=ma9.2.56, a=1556722142, adid=2d68a735-0d98-4e3f-9588-07ade43f9ff6, aid=com.example.sibadityamaiti.myapplication, an=My Application, ate=1, av=1.0, cd=HEllo world, cd11=NA, cd12=NA, cd13=NA, cd14=NA, cd15=NA, cd20=NA, cd6=NA, cd7=NA, cd8=NA, cid=8f3adfc2-2cbe-49c0-b2b3-d3913ff4e5f9, sr=1080x1920, t=appview, tid=UA-36768858-15, uid=NA, ul=en-in, v=1
06-11 15:02:34.672 22292 22932 D GAv4    : Hit delivery requested: ht=1497173554553, _s=23, _v=ma9.2.56, a=1556722143, adid=2d68a735-0d98-4e3f-9588-07ade43f9ff6, aid=com.example.sibadityamaiti.myapplication, an=My Application, ate=1, av=1.0, cd=HEllo world, cd11=NA, cd12=NA, cd13=NA, cd14=NA, cd15=NA, cd20=NA, cd6=NA, cd7=NA, cd8=NA, cid=8f3adfc2-2cbe-49c0-b2b3-d3913ff4e5f9, sr=1080x1920, t=appview, tid=UA-36768858-8, uid=NA, ul=en-in, v=1
06-11 15:02:34.734 22292 22932 D GAv4    : Hit sent to the device AnalyticsService for delivery
06-11 15:02:34.755 22292 22932 D GAv4    : Hit sent to the device AnalyticsService for delivery
```

The Log shows two event fired however there was only one click event.
This can lead to corrupted ga analytics.

This is dependency i am using.

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:9.2.1'
```

Any help will be appreciated. Let me know if anyone needs more information.

Comment: Any specific reason you're calling `prepareTagManager` twice? This is initializing two GTM containers and is most likely causing your double event firing.

Comment: Yeah, because we have two containers. One is full. Also I tried with one prepare tag manager call as well. Same result

Comment: When you are registering two containers, it's normal for there to be two hits. If you look at your hits, one of them is going to property with ID UA-36768858-15 and the other is going to property with ID UA-36768858-8. If, after removing the initialization of one of the containers, you're still seeing two tags firing, then the only explanation is that you have two tags configured to trigger in response to this event in the same container.

Comment: @faridghar thanks for your reply. Checking the same. will let you know the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We hopefully found the problem. There are no double data layer push calls here.
Its a problem with the robustness of TagManager lib itself.

The main problem is. If you call tagmanager init twice for single application instance.
TagManager will start misbehaving by sending double or triple hits.

In my sample app which i posted here. Which has one activity.
In its onCreate calling Tag Manager Init. One single button. Its onclick to send one push on datalayer.
new sample container. Even this minimum setup was able to reproduce this bug.

As in our case we were initialising GTM in Launcher Activity OnCreate. Press back and come back again.
As launcher will get created again. It will call Init again. But for this case Application instance was not recreated.

The solution to this for us was to move this Init Tag manager code to Application OnCreate. Rather in any Activity.
In our dev testing. We found it fixed now.

For Google team :

1. The tagmanager doc should mention to **prefer  TagManager init in Application class**. Rather in any Activty. If its already mentioned. 
    Then i probably ignored it. It should be highlighted as it can effect GA for a product.
2. TagManager should be more robust to handle multiple init for single app instance.